IpVanish VPN failed to connect
I am trying to install IpVanish on Ubuntu 23.10, but I get connection failure every time, the activation of the network connection has failed
VPN settings:

IPV6 settings:


yes , they are correct

they didn't respond

Are you using the openVPN or the Wireguard protocol? All the instructions I could find in IPVanish site specifies port 443. The picture in your question shows port 1080. Which instruction did you follow? Add the link to the instructions you followed to your question.

I have this working for ubuntu 24, they have added a special config file here for the issues. https://support.ipvanish.com/hc/en-us/articles/12976094099867-OpenVPN-not-working-in-Linux-Windows-OpenVPN-Client

I got it to work by monitoring the logs using tail -f /var/log/syslog and then attempting to import an IPVanish .ovpn config file (IIRC).
Anyway... the config files are out of date, they contain deprecated setttings viz.:

comp-lzo
keysize 256

Removing these options for me restored the functionality expected.

This is the right answer. Removed those two settings from the desired config file and it worked for me on Ubuntu 24.04

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS is the last version to work with IPVanish, in my experiences. 23.1, a beta (non LTS) did not work. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS does not work with IPVanish. I informed IPVanish via chat, which is supposedly getting escalated to the programmers, and what I would term a trouble ticket, and another way. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS will be around for a decade, and this will get sorted out, hopefully including Wireguard. I am retired and have spent many hours on this, and the ball is in the IPVanish-court. IPVanish is working on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS right here and now, and that's the version to use until the 'bug' is fixed. The latest instructions are at https://support.ipvanish.com/hc/en-us/articles/12975503218203-OpenVPN-setup-in-Ubuntu-22-04-1 which does also work with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and was having the same issue.
I resolved it by the following:
Disabled IPV6 for all connections via command line
I also had to disable IPV6 for my main internet connection via the GUI. Settings > Network > PCI Ethernet ( or whatever your main connection is ) > Settings > IPV6 tab > use the slider to "disable" ipv6
That took care of it for me.
